# inline PHP in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have used inline PHP in HTML, the file extension is .php and it does not seem to work in both cases

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>index.php">Home<?php echo "home";?></a></li>
```

where $link is defined as

```
<?php
 $link="pages/";
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does it not work? What actually happens?

Comment: The code is fine, you must explain a little bit more.

Comment: The link does not open `http://localhost:8080/mysite/%3C?php%20echo%20$link;%20?%3Eindex.php`

Comment: and a 403 error when I click on the link

Comment: Based on your comment, your PHP isn't being executed. What webserver are you using?

Comment: i am using xamp,local host

Comment: should I re-install xamp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score -1):

- make sure that your XAMPP server is running
- make sure that your file inside C:/xampp/htdocs/mysite/